# Traceback error when i execute my python 3 program

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, request, traceback

```
import requests
  
response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/')

json_response = response.json()
repository = json_response['item'][0]

print(f'Respository name: {repository["name"]}')
print(f'Repository description: {repository["description"]}')
```

it displays a traceback error at runtime

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Please post the actual error prompt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The .json() method is for decoding responses containing JSON data, the url in your code returns HTML data, and it can't be parsed as JSON.

Comment: So what's the solution in code